# how to create an azure service bus (topic) subscription and list existing subscriptions via code?

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

A 3rd party supplies data via azure service bus, but it exists in their name space on their azure subscription, so we cant create topic subscriptions via the portal.

They have given us a connection string and list of topic names.

We need to list existing topic subscriptions, and create new ones via code. Either a console app, or function app.  Unfortunately, our devs are all java and javascript, so we are new to C#.

We have found tutorials on sending and receiving messages, but none to create a subscription given a connection string and topic name, and none to list all existing subscriptions (and even delete old ones).

Basically manage an azure message bus without access to the Azure portal namespace.

Comment: Are you using any SDK?

Comment: I have installed various versions of .net and .net core SDKs.  on windows, I cant get the dotnet command to work, despite istalling the ofiicial .net 6 runtime and sdk. On mac, It works, but if I try to install and run tools like https://github.com/sszlachetka/ServiceBusAdmin on mac, it says I need to install another SDK (which I am guessing isnt available on mac)

Answer (score 0):

The SDK you would want to use is [`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/). This is the latest SDK for managing Service Bus at the time of writing this answer and should work for .Net Core.

The Namespace for managing entities (Queues, Topics etc.) is [`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration?view=azure-dotnet).

To list Topics in the Namespace, you would first create an instance of [`ServiceBusAdministrationClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet) and then use [`ServiceBusAdministrationClient.GetTopicsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.gettopicsasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-administration-servicebusadministrationclient-gettopicsasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method.

Similarly to create a Topic in the Namespace, you would create an instance of `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` and then use [`ServiceBusAdministrationClient.CreateTopicAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.createtopicasync?view=azure-dotnet) method.